# How to add button to NavBar while ViewController is embeded in as TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I try to add refresh button programmatically to my `NavBar`, while I am in `TabBarController` and I have a big problem with that. This is my code in `ViewDidLoad()`:

```
let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, target: self, action: "refreshData")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
```

any suggestions?

This is my storyboard after launch my app (no icon):

[image: No icon]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `viewController` embed in `UINavigationController` first then add this navigation controller into `tabViewController`'s view controllers array. After that use the method below:

```
 let refresh = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
 //Set refresh image
 refresh.setImage(UIImage(named: "refresh"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
 //or set text title
 refresh.setTitle("Refresh", forState: .Normal)
 refresh.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: refresh)
```

**EDIT:**
what's your navBar? It's `UINavigationBar`, yes, it's possible:

```
let item = UINavigationItem(title: "")
item.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Refresh", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action:"refresh")
item.hidesBackButton = true
UINavigationBar().pushNavigationItem(item, animated: false)
```

But normally it's should be embed in `UINavigationController`

Comment: First there's a typos i have changed the last line from 'menu' to 'refresh'. Does your view controller embed in a UINavigationController?

Comment: I saw your typos I changed it. No, my `VievController` is embed in `TabBarController`

Comment: I think your self.navigationItem is null, check my edit again.

Comment: I did everything correct but it doesn't work, sorry:(

Comment: If you say everything correct who can help you? Maybe paste more code.

Comment: the problem is I don't have embed in `Navigation Controller` but `TabBarController` and the question is. Is any possibility to add button to `navbar` when I have embed in `TabBarController` or it isn't possible.

Comment: thank you for your help, but this solution doesn't work too. When I write `NavBar` I have `UINavigationBar` in my mind.